# php script return true suddenly stopped returning value

Tags: php, opencart

I have a function in my PHP script which restores data from backup. Everything was fine and working well, until suddenly it stopped working after months of working well. I am using OC 2.2.0 and this function is supposed to restore products and their data from `oc_product_backup` table. I `print_r` every step so that I would see where the problem is, and realized that when it gets to:

```
return true;
```

it never happens. What could be wrong all of the sudden, and how do I make this work? I never had this kind of problem. My function looks like this:

```
function restoreBackup()
{
    global $mysqli;

    $i               = 0;
    $getpic          = "SELECT * FROM oc_product_backup LIMIT 0, 100000";
    $backup          = $mysqli->query($getpic);

    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE); 
    $updateproduct_sql     = "UPDATE oc_product SET image = ?, modified_by = ?, date_modified = ? WHERE product_id= ?";
    $updatedescription_sql = "UPDATE oc_product_description SET meta_description = ?, meta_keyword = ?, tag = ?, modified_by = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND language_id = ?";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($updateproduct_sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('siss', $image, $modified_by, $date_modified, $product_id);
    //print_r ($updateproduct_sql);
    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($updatedescription_sql);
    $stmt2->bind_param('sssisi', $meta_description, $meta_keyword, $tag, $modified_by, $product_id, $language_id);
    //print_r($updatedescription_sql);

    while($row = $backup->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {

        //$name              = removeslashes($row['name']);
        //$name              = $row['name'];
        //$description       = removeslashes($row['description']);
        //$description       = $row['description'];
        $meta_description  = $row['meta_description'];
        $meta_keyword      = $row['meta_keyword'];
        $tag               = $row['tag'];
        $product_id        = $row['product_id'];
        $modified_by       = $row['modified_by']; 
        $language_id       = $row['language_id'];
        //if($row['language_id'] == 1)
        //{
        $image          = $row['image'];
        //$ean            = $row['ean'];
        //$name           = $row['name'];
        //$model          = $row['model'];
        //$status         = $row['status'];
        $price_sync     = $row['price_sync'];
        $date_modified  = $row['date_modified']; 

        if(!$stmt->execute())
            return false;

        //}
        if(!$stmt2->execute())
            return false;

        $i++;
        if(($i % 500) === 0) $mysqli->commit();

    }

    $mysqli->commit();
    $backup->close(); //the last line that gets executed
    return true; //this never happens
    writeToLog('- Backup restored');
}
```

Comment: Maybe your script is timing out because the data in the db got more? (just a suggestion, don't crucify me)

Comment: @SchalkKeun Thanx for your reply - my DB didn't get significantly bigger over the time, so I don't think this would be the problem. But thanx for the suggestion, anyway.

Comment: are you getting a blank page or a Network Timed out page? Is this script being executed on a browser or as a cron job?

Comment: I am getting a blank page(no errors reported whatsoever)  and I run the script in a browser. @SchalkKeun

Comment: ok. the try to do a `echo '<pre>';print_r($row);echo '</pre>';` just after the opening `while` loop. and see if it is actually returning and iterating through the data?

Comment: I just tried it and yes, it does return and iterate through the data. ˇ@SchalkKeun

Comment: next you should look at the execute() statements that returns false. Your problem is there. It is not properly writing data and then returns the false and exits your loop.

Comment: Thanx, but what do you mean it doesn't write data properly, when it is iterating through data properly? Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code a bit, it seems like your prepared statements binding the data was outside of the loop, so technically it would never have written any data.

```
function restoreBackup() {
    global $mysqli;

    $i = 0;
    $getpic = "SELECT * FROM oc_product_backup LIMIT 0, 100000";
    $backup = $mysqli - > query($getpic);

    $mysqli - > autocommit(FALSE);
    $updateproduct_sql = "UPDATE oc_product SET image = ?, modified_by = ?, date_modified = ? WHERE product_id= ?";
    $updatedescription_sql = "UPDATE oc_product_description SET meta_description = ?, meta_keyword = ?, tag = ?, modified_by = ? WHERE product_id = ? AND language_id = ?";


    while ($row = $backup - > fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $meta_description = $row['meta_description'];
        $meta_keyword = $row['meta_keyword'];
        $tag = $row['tag'];
        $product_id = $row['product_id'];
        $modified_by = $row['modified_by'];
        $language_id = $row['language_id'];
        $image = $row['image'];
        $price_sync = $row['price_sync'];
        $date_modified = $row['date_modified'];

        $stmt = $mysqli - > prepare($updateproduct_sql);
        $stmt - > bind_param('siss', $image, $modified_by, $date_modified, $product_id);
        if (!$stmt - > execute())
            return false;

        $stmt2 = $mysqli - > prepare($updatedescription_sql);
        $stmt2 - > bind_param('sssisi', $meta_description, $meta_keyword, $tag, $modified_by, $product_id, $language_id);
        if (!$stmt2 - > execute())
            return false;

        $i++;
        if (($i % 500) === 0) $mysqli - > commit();

    }

    $mysqli - > commit();
    $backup - > close(); //the last line that gets executed
    return true; //this never happens
    writeToLog('- Backup restored');
}
```

Comment: Your solution should work, but it simply doesn't. I have no idea what is happening, I am losing my mind.

Comment: @Nancy, I would suggest that you just throw `print_r()` everywhere to make sure that all your data actually gets written like it is suppose to.

Comment: Thanx for trying to help. I did print_r() everything and everything seems just fine, except that it doesn't work what it should. I will try more and post an answer here once I figure this out. If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.